# How to slide animate and make a view visible from right to left in Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to make a view visible with slide animation effect from right to left and vise versa. I've successfully been able to hide a view with left to right slide animation but unable to achieve the other one.
Following is the code snippet that I'm using :

```
private void showLayout(){
    if(mContainerLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        mContainerLayout.animate()
                .translationX(mContainerLayout.getWidth())
                .setDuration(300)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        mContainerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }).start();
    }
    else{
        mContainerLayout.animate()
                .translationX(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        mContainerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add a fade animation instead:

```
private void showLayout(boolean show){
    if (show){
        mContainerLayout.animate()
                .translationX(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .alpha(1)
                .start();
    } else {
        mContainerLayout.animate()
                .translationX(mContainerLayout.getWidth())
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `slide_in_anim.xml` inside `anim` folder under `res` folder  and add this code

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate
      android:duration="200"
      android:fillAfter="true"
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

Then use this animation as

```
Animation slideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_up);
mContainerLayout.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
```